# Hide CPT from users unless logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called `Documents` which has a taxonomy called `documentcats` all of which needs to be accessed by logged in users only.

I have used this from another thread:

```
add_filter( 'wp', 'f040925b_redirect', 0 );
function f040925b_redirect( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if(
        (
            $post->post_type == 'documents'
            ||
            is_post_type_archive( 'documents' )
            ||
            is_tax( 'documentcat' )
        )
        &&
        !is_user_logged_in()
    ) {
        wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
        exit;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

However, as the posts are searchable, this is preventing the wordpress search functionality working and redirects all searches back to the homepage.

Can anyone suggest how I can completely hide the post type and it's taxonomy page, archive page etc.. from anyone who's not logged in without breaking the search functionality?

Thanks

Comment: i checked and it seems to be working. however if you search the terms that will bring up the document post type as result only then it will move to homepage.

Comment: Did you create the custom post type? If so, you should have registered it in the `init` action, at which point the user is already authenticated or not. So you can just use `is_user_logged_in` prior to registering the post type. If they're not logged in, it doesn't even exist for them (it still exists in your database and for logged in users - but WordPress won't be aware of it for non-logged-in users).